# asp.net ListView or Repeater grouping by three

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am using a nice shopping cart I found online. I would like to translate this code to use a repeater or listview and dynamically retrieve my data, but I cannot seem to find a way to group my data correctly.

I know the ListView can group by a certain amount of items, but I have not found a way to do it with this scenario.

The shopping cart works by having a ul list of items, followed by their details in the div below. This process starts again by getting three more ul items, followed by three more details. How could I do this using a ListView or repeater? I have not found a way to repeat both of these sets of data I need in a group of three. Any thoughts?

```
    <ul>
        <li id="1">  
            <div>Red Grocery Bag</div>
        </li>

        <li id="2">
            <div>Reusable Grocery Bag</div>
        </li>

        <li id="3">
            <div>White Grocery Bag</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="detail-view" id="detail-1">             

        <div class="detail_info">                   
            <label class='item_name'>Red Grocery Bag</label>

            <p>
                shopping bag, shopping, bag, merchandise, consumerism, gift:                    
                <br /><br/>
                $<span class="price">80.00</span>                       
            </p>                    
        </div>              
    </div>
    <div class="detail-view" id="detail-2">

        <div class="detail_info">                   
            <label class='item_name'>Reusable Grocery Bag</label>
            <p>
                shopping bag, shopping, bag, merchandise, consumerism, gift:                    
                <br /><br />
                $<span class="price">70.00</span>                       
            </p>                    
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="detail-view" id="detail-3">

        <div class="detail_info">                   
            <label class='item_name'>White Grocery Bag</label>

            <p>
                shopping bag, shopping, bag, merchandise, consumerism, gift:
                <br /><br />
                $<span class="price">50.00</span>                       
            </p>
        </div>              
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### **<kbd>Mark Up for Repeater and Datalist will behave in the following way only</kbd>**

```
<asp:datalist id="rpt" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <ul>
        <li>  
            <div><%# Eval("Bag") %></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="detail-view">             
        <div class="detail_info">                   
            <label class='item_name'><%# Eval("Bag") %></label>
            <p>
                <%# Eval("YourColumn") %>
                <br /><br/>
                $<span class="price"><%# Eval("Price") %></span>                       
            </p>                    
        </div>              
    </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:datalist>
```

---

Alternatively, use two <kbd>Repeaters</kbd> first for ul and next for div

Comment: Thanks Nilish! This would be one by one. How could I make it work with three li's dynamically followed by three details dyanmically? Then I have to repeat this three / three pattern.

Comment: Alternative is to use two repeaters first for ul and next for div